# SQL Query in NHibernate diction

Tags: sql, nhibernate

I have a SQL Query which works in SQL Management Studio:

Select Id 
From table t
Where t.Date=
  (Select Max(Date)
   From (
      Select * 
      From table where ReferenceId = xy) u)

Reason is, from all entries with a certain foreign key, I want to receive the one with
the highest date.

I tried to reform this Query for use in NHibernate, and I got

```
IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(String.Format(
            @"Select t.Id  
            From table t
            Where t.Date =
                (Select Max(Date)
                From (Select * 
                      From table t where t.ReferenceItem.Id = " + item.ReferenceItem.Id + ")u)"));
```

I get the error message: "In expected"

How do I have to form the NHibernate query? What does the "In" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the "in expected" means that there is a mismatch on the mapping and the query trying to run.

HQL queries expect tokens as they are mapped to your classes. As such they are very limited to their SQL capabilities: they only allow what the selected Dialect allows.

Answer (score 3):

To execute **SQL** queries, you must use `CreateSQLQuery` instead of `CreateQuery`.

The latter creates **HQL** queries.

Comment: +1 I not even paid attention to the query so I made a wrong assumption

Answer (score 1):

You should verify your mapping file properties to see if you're using Embedded Resourse, otherwise, you'll keep getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I could build the query correctly, it should be

```
"Select t.Id  
            From table t
            Where t.Date =
                (Select Max(u.Date)
                From table u where u.ReferenceItem.Id = " + item.ReferenceItem.Id + ")"
```